# Palindrome says infinity when compared in the final if statement

Tags: javascript, html

ok so I have been going at it for a while im making a palindrome program on html for the first time but when I input 111 it says its not a palindrome even tho i went through the while loop with a calc and it should be the same. I checked the outputs by revealing em and
"input" = 111.
"temp" = 0 as it should.
"reversed" tho is equal to infinity lol and idk y any help is appreciated.

```
function Palindrome() {
    let input = document.querySelector("#userInput").value;
    var temp = input;
    let reversed = 0;

    while (temp > 0) {
        const lastDigit = temp % 10;
        reversed = (reversed * 10) + lastDigit;
        temp = (temp / 10);
    }
    if (input == reversed) {
        document.querySelector("#answer").innerHTML = `This is a Palindrome `;
    }else {
        document.querySelector("#answer").innerHTML = `This is not a Palindrome ${input} ${temp} ${reversed} `;
    }
}
```

Comment: `var temp = input;` convert input to number first by using `parseInt(input)`

Comment: Put `console.log(temp, lastDigit);` into the loop and you'll see the problem.

Comment: @TAHERElMehdi While that's a good idea, it's not the problem because `%` and `*` will automatically convert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing floating point division, so `temp` will never be more than 0 until you do many iterations and get floating point underflow. After each iteration it becomes `11.1`, then `1.11`, then `0.111`, `.0111`, and so on. This is multiplying `reversed` by 10 each time, and it eventually overflows to infinity.

Round the number when dividing so that the fraction will be discarded:

```
temp = Math.round(temp / 10);
```

```js
function Palindrome(input) {
  var temp = input;
  let reversed = 0;

  while (temp > 0) {
    const lastDigit = temp % 10;
    reversed = (reversed * 10) + lastDigit;
    temp = Math.round(temp / 10);
  }
  if (input == reversed) {
    console.log(`This is a Palindrome ${input}`);
  } else {
    console.log(`This is not a Palindrome ${input} ${temp} ${reversed} `);
  }
}

Palindrome(111);
Palindrome(123)
```

Comment: thank you it worked but i dont understand why would I need to clarify the round and why is it going to 0.111 when i do it on the calc it doesnt round or does it lol

Comment: maybe im just used to integer

Comment: If you're used to C, it doesn't automatically convert to floating point.

Answer (score 1):

As Barmar explained in his answer about percent division try to git rid of it!

```js
function Palindrome() {
  let input = document.querySelector("#userInput").value;
  //convert input to number
  var temp = +input;//or parseInt(input)
  let reversed = 0;
  while (temp > 0) {
    const lastDigit = temp % 10;
    reversed = reversed * 10 + lastDigit;
    temp = Math.floor(temp / 10);//<-- to prevent Infinity
  }
  if (input == reversed) {
    document.querySelector("#answer").innerHTML = `This is a Palindrome `;
  } else {
    document.querySelector(
      "#answer"
    ).innerHTML = `This is not a Palindrome ${input} ${temp} ${reversed} `;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="input" value="" id="userInput">
<input type="button" value="Is Palindrom" onclick="Palindrome()">
<div id='answer'></div>
```